# How can I create a slowly moving button as if it is animated?

Tags: java

I'd like a button that moves in increments (sort of as if animated) when clicked. This code causes the button to move, but it only shows the beginning and end position (and not the increments in between). I'd prefer to use code most similar to this present code for now, but I'm open to learning new ideas for the future as well.

How can I create a slowly moving button as if it is animated?

```
 public void onButtonClick3(final View view) throws InterruptedException {

        for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        long timer1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long timer2 = System.currentTimeMillis();


                    ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams vlp = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();

            do {
                sleep(300);
                timer2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
            while (timer1 + 1 > timer2);


            int leftMargin = vlp.leftMargin;
            int topMargin = vlp.topMargin;

            ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
            params.width = 200;
            params.leftMargin = leftMargin + 100;
            params.topMargin = topMargin + 100;
            view.setLayoutParams(params);
        }        
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: This seems to be JavaFX and thus I'm not sure whether there is an event dispatch thread or not but I'd assume there is one. Thus you might want to do the animation (and it _is_ an animation not just sort of) in a worker thread in order not to block the thread that handles the display updates - that's what seems to be the cause for you not seeing the intermediate positions.

Comment: I don't think that moving controls around is a good idea - this is what you have layout managers for. In any case, look at [`Timeline`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html). If you want more help, post a [mcve].

Comment: Most of my coding has been in VBA-Excel (where I am making games). I am teaching myself Java to try and convert a couple of my games into apps for Android devices. Eventually, I hope to have an extensive Java experience to convert all of my games, but for now I am just hoping to make a few codes that most resemble the way I already have it done in VBA. If I change the code approach too far from the VBA code, then it can potentially make future coding challenges.

Thanks for your comments. Albeit, I'm not sure that I've managed to make any progress.

Comment: I don't think you fully understood me. You should [edit] your question with a [mcve] (read the link) that demonstrates the problem. We need top be able to copy-paste it and run it and see the problem ourselves. This way we can recommend a solution.

Comment: Also, use @username to reply in comments.

Comment: @Thomas
I am not sure that animation will be my ticket, but could you give me short example to point me in the right direction? I'll throw it in google to see if that helps as well. Thanks you so much for the suggestion!

Comment: @user1803551,
Thanks for the posting tips. I began coding in Java less than a week ago and have trouble shortening the code any further (this is the shortened version, believe it or not). If it were VBA code, I would feel a little more confident. I'm just trying to get over that awkward beginner phase once again. 
Thanks for your patience!

Comment: You don't need to shorten it, you need to make it run for us. We don't know what calls `onButtonClick3`, we don't know what `View` is, we have no GUI on which we can press a button and see what's wrong. It seems to me that you have a full version where you have a button and it doesn't move the way you want. The version you gave us doesn't have that. Your version probably also has a lot of things unrelated to the problem. Find the middle ground where you show us everything that we need and only what we need. This is an important skill to learn in isolating problems.

Comment: @user1803551

Would it help if I shared my VBA code? I really don't know enough about java to provide what you are suggesting. I could easily do it in VBA, however.

Comment: You wrote "*This code causes the button to move, but it only shows the beginning and end position*", so you have some code that does that, it's *not* the code you posted because that code cannot be ran. Where is the code that you ran, noticed that it doesn't work and caused you to ask the question?